# Best way to translate Latin letters to English letters

Tags: c#, utf-8

I need to translate a text which is written in English and Latin characters to only English letters. 
example ŴỔRḐ = WORD.

I've created a dictionary with most of the possible mapping.
I know I missed some of the mappings, and I would like to know what is the best solution/mapping for this problem.

This is the dictionary:

```
IDictionary<string, string> LatinMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {   

        { "á", a }, { "Á", A }, { "à", a }, { "À", A }, { "â", a }, { "Â", A }, { "ä", a }, { "Ä", A },
        { "ă", a }, { "Ă", A }, { "ā", a }, { "Ā", A }, { "ã", a }, { "Ã", A }, { "å", a }, { "Å", A },
        { "ầ", a }, { "Ầ", A }, { "ắ", a }, { "Ắ", A }, { "ằ", a }, { "Ằ", A }, { "ẵ", a }, { "Ẵ", A },
        { "ả", a }, { "Ả", A }, { "ạ", a }, { "Ạ", A }, { "ậ", a }, { "Ậ", A }, { "ấ", a }, { "Ấ", A },
        { "ą", a }, { "Ą", A },

        { "æ", "ae" }, { "Æ", "AE" }, { "ǣ", "ae" }, { "Ǣ", "AE" },
        { "ß", b }, { "þ", b }, { "Þ", B },

        { "ć", c }, { "Ć", C }, { "č", c }, { "Č", C }, { "ç", c }, { "Ç", C }, { "ĉ", c }, { "Ĉ", C },
        { "ċ", c }, { "Ċ", C },
        { "ḑ", d }, { "Ḑ", D }, { "đ", d }, { "Đ", D }, { "ð", d }, { "Ð", D }, { "ḍ", d }, { "Ḍ", D },
        { "ď", d }, { "Ď", D },
        { "é", e }, { "É", E }, { "è", e }, { "È", E }, { "ė", e }, { "Ė", E }, { "ê", e }, { "Ê", E },
        { "ë", e }, { "Ë", E }, { "ě", e }, { "Ě", E }, { "ĕ", e }, { "Ĕ", E }, { "ē", e }, { "Ē", E },
        { "ę", e }, { "Ę", E }, { "ế", e }, { "Ế", E }, { "ề", e }, { "Ề", E }, { "ệ", e }, { "Ệ", E },
        { "ǝ", e }, { "Ǝ", E }, { "ə", e }, { "Ə", E }, { "ể", e }, { "Ể", E }, { "ễ", e }, { "Ễ", E },
        { "ẹ̀", e }, { "Ẹ̀", E }, { "ɛ́", e }, { "ɛ", e }, { "Ɛ", E },

        { "ğ", g }, { "Ğ", G }, { "ĝ", g }, { "Ĝ", G }, { "ġ", g }, { "Ġ", G }, { "ģ", g }, { "Ģ", G },
        { "ḩ", h }, { "Ḩ", H }, { "ħ", h }, { "Ħ", H }, { "ḥ", h }, { "Ḥ", H }, { "ĥ", h }, { "Ĥ", H },
        { "ẖ", h }, { "H̱", H }, { "h̲", h }, { "H̲", H },

        { "ı", i }, { "ı".ToUpper(), I }, { "í", i }, { "Í", I }, { "ì", i }, { "Ì", I }, { "İ".ToLower(), i }, { "İ", I },
        { "î", i }, { "Î", I }, { "ï", i }, { "Ï", I }, { "ĭ", i }, { "Ĭ", I }, { "ī", i }, { "Ī", I },
        { "ĩ", i }, { "Ĩ", I }, { "ỉ", i }, { "Ỉ", I }, { "ị", i }, { "Ị", I },
        { "ķ", k }, { "Ķ", K },
        { "ļ", l }, { "Ļ", L }, { "ł", l }, { "Ł", L }, { "ľ", l }, { "Ľ", L },
        { "ň", n }, { "Ň", N }, { "ñ", n }, { "Ñ", N }, { "ń", n }, { "Ń", N }, { "ŋ", n }, { "Ŋ", N },
        { "ņ", n }, { "Ņ", N },

        { "ó", o }, { "Ó", O }, { "ò", o }, { "Ò", O }, { "ô", o }, { "Ô", O }, { "ö", o }, { "Ö", O },
        { "ŏ", o }, { "Ŏ", O }, { "ō", o }, { "Ō", O }, { "õ", o }, { "Õ", O }, { "ő", o }, { "Ő", O },
        { "ố", o }, { "Ố", O }, { "ồ", o }, { "Ồ", O }, { "ø", o }, { "Ø", O }, { "ơ", o }, { "Ơ", O },
        { "ọ", o }, { "Ọ", O }, { "ớ", o }, { "Ớ", O }, { "ộ", o }, { "Ộ", O }, { "ɔ", o }, { "Ɔ", O },
        { "ɔ́", o }, { "Ɔ́", O }, { "ổ", o }, { "Ổ", O }, { "ỏ", o }, { "Ỏ", O },

        { "œ", oe }, { "Œ", OE }, { "œ̆", oe }, { "Œ̆", OE },

        { "ř", r }, { "Ř", R }, { "ŗ", r }, { "Ŗ", R },
        { "ś", s }, { "Ś", S }, { "š", s }, { "Š", S }, { "ş", s }, { "Ş", S }, { "ṣ", s }, { "Ṣ", S },
        { "ŝ", s }, { "Ŝ", S }, { "ș", s }, { "s̲", s }, { "S̲", S },
        { "ţ", t }, { "Ţ", T }, { "ṭ", t }, { "Ṭ", T }, { "ŧ", t }, { "Ŧ", T }, { "ț", t }, { "ť", t }, { "Ť", T },

        { "ú", u }, { "Ú", U }, { "ù", u }, { "Ù", U }, { "ü", u }, { "Ü", U }, { "ŭ", u }, { "Ŭ", U },
        { "ū", u }, { "Ū", U }, { "ũ", u }, { "Ũ", U }, { "ų", u }, { "Ų", U }, { "ủ", u }, { "Ủ", U },
        { "ư", u }, { "Ư", U }, { "ừ", u }, { "Ừ", U }, { "û", u }, { "Û", U }, { "ự", u }, { "Ự", U },
        { "ů", u }, { "Ů", U }, { "ụ", u }, { "Ụ", U }, { "ṳ", u }, { "Ṳ", U }, { "ứ", u }, { "Ứ", U },

        { "ŵ", w }, { "Ŵ", W },
        { "ý", y }, { "Ý", Y }, { "ỹ", y }, { "Ỹ", Y }, { "ỳ", y }, { "Ỳ", Y },
        { "ź", z }, { "Ź", Z }, { "ž", z }, { "Ž", Z }, { "z̄", z }, { "Z̄", Z }, { "z̧", z }, { "Z̧", Z },
        { "ż", z }, { "Ż", Z }, { "ẕ", z }, { "Ẕ", Z },

    };


public static string TranslateLatingToEnglishLetters(string text)
        {

        foreach (var conversion in LatinMapping)
        {
            text = text.Replace(conversion.Key, conversion.Value);                
        }

        return text;
    }
```

Comment: (no need to do `.Contains` first -- `.Replace` will return the original string if the thing to replace isn't found)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net

Comment: @canton7 Thanks Edited!

Comment: This code is not going to be very quick. In .NET strings are immutable, meaning every replacement you do creates an entirely new string. You should really use `StringBuilder`, it has a `Replace` method on it too.

Comment: In most situations, you should map 'ß' (sharp s) to 'ss' and 'þ'/'Þ' (thorn) to 'th'/'Th'. These letters are in no way related to 'b'.